# Python error using Tkinter (.get)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having an issue pulling variable from entry widgets, so far I have done this but I can't find my error. I am using python 3.

```
from tkinter import *

def main():
    global today,postal,user,expire,cardnum
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Card checker")
    instruction =Label(root, text="Please enter your card details\n")
    namel = Label(root, text="Name: ")
    post = Label(root, text="Postal code: ")
    today_date = Label(root, text="Todays date: ")
    expire_date = Label(root, text="Expiry date ")
    card_number = Label(root, text="Card Number: ")
    date1= ()
    postcode= ()
    name1= ()
    expire1= ()
    cardno = ()

    namel.grid(row=1, column =0)
    post.grid(row=2,  column =0)
    today_date.grid(row=3,  column =0)
    expire_date.grid(row=4,  column =0)
    card_number.grid(row=5,  column =0)
    todaydateE= Entry(root,textvariable=date1)
    postE= Entry(root,textvariable=postcode)
    nameE = Entry(root,textvariable=name1)
    expiredateE= Entry(root,textvariable=expire1)
    cardnumberE= Entry(root,textvariable=cardno)
    nameE.grid(row=1, column =1)
    postE.grid(row=2,  column =1)
    cardnumberE.grid(row=5,  column =1)
    expiredateE.grid(row=4,  column =1)
    todaydateE.grid(row=3,  column =1)

    doneButton = Button(root, text= "Confirm", command=datecheck)
    doneButton.grid(columnspan =2)
    today= date1.get()
    postal= (postcode.get())
    user= name1.get()
    expire= expire1.get()
    cardnum = cardno.get()


def datecheck():
    global today,postal,user,expire,cardnum
    print(postal)
```

Comment: Post all code here directly. Don't link to code. You also need to actually describe your problem.

Comment: After reviewing your code there are several problems with it. However you wont likely get an answer until you have posted your code and trackback error in your questions.

Answer (score 0):

So you weren't using the .get() function correctly. Also you want to make the program so that you .get() something after an event otherwise it will try to get nothing because when the program starts up there will be nothing there. Edited your code so that if you hit the confirm button you'll get whatever is entered into the entry boxes

```
from tkinter import *

def datecheck():
    global today, postal, user, expire, cardnum
    today = todaydateE.get()
    postal = (postE.get())
    user = nameE.get()
    expire = expiredateE.get()
    cardnum = cardnumberE.get()
    print(postal)

global today, postal, user, expire, cardnum
root = Tk()
root.title("Card checker")
instruction = Label(root, text="Please enter your card details\n")
namel = Label(root, text="Name: ")
post = Label(root, text="Postal code: ")
today_date = Label(root, text="Todays date: ")
expire_date = Label(root, text="Expiry date ")
card_number = Label(root, text="Card Number: ")

namel.grid(row=1, column=0)
post.grid(row=2, column=0)
today_date.grid(row=3, column=0)
expire_date.grid(row=4, column=0)
card_number.grid(row=5, column=0)
todaydateE = Entry(root)
postE = Entry(root)
nameE = Entry(root)
expiredateE = Entry(root )
cardnumberE = Entry(root)
nameE.grid(row=1, column=1)
postE.grid(row=2, column=1)
cardnumberE.grid(row=5, column=1)
expiredateE.grid(row=4, column=1)
todaydateE.grid(row=3, column=1)

doneButton = Button(root, text="Confirm", command=datecheck)
doneButton.grid(columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```